# Match SpatialPoints to Delaunay Triangles in R

Tags: r, delaunay

I have 2 SpatialPointsDataFrame files. I compute the Delaunay Triangles from the first shapefile (`shp1`) as in the code below. Then I wish to assign each point from my second shapefile (`shp2`) to one of the Delaunay Triangles held within the object vtess.

```
vtess <- deldir(shp1$coords.x1,shp1$coords.x2)
```

I can assign each `shp2` point to a tessellation *tile* in the following way:

```
tl <- tile.list(vtess)
shp2$tile <- 99
for (i in 1:length(shp2$tile)){
   shp2$tile[i] <- which.tile(shp2$coords.x1[i], shp2$coords.x2[i], tl)
}
```

However, while I can find the list of triangles using `triang.list(vtess)`, there is no `which.triang` command, so it is not possible to similarly assign `shp2` points to triangles.

I'm guessing I therefore need to (1) create a SpatialPolygon of the triangles, and then (2) overlap the `shp2` points to the new polygon file. Is this the most efficient way? And if so, how do I create a polygon shapefile from the triangles held within `vtess`?

Cross-posted, with no reply, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700872/match-spatialpoints-to-delaunay-triangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how - use `triang.list` to get the points that make the triangles, then wrap it all up in some code that constructs `SpatialPolygons` from the `sp` package. Then do an overlay test.

Sample data:

```
library(sp)
library(deldir)
pts1 = data.frame(ID=LETTERS, x=runif(26),y=runif(26))
pts2 = data.frame(ID=LETTERS, x=runif(26),y=runif(26))
coordinates(pts1)=~x+y
coordinates(pts2)=~x+y
```

make the tesselation:

```
vtess=deldir(pts1@coords[,1],pts1@coords[,2])
```

build triangles:

```
tl = triang.list(vtess)
```

then this monster builds the triangles into spatial polygons:

```
polys = SpatialPolygons(
  lapply(1:length(tl),
         function(i){
           Polygons(
             list(
               Polygon(tl[[i]][c(1:3,1),c("x","y")])
                 ),ID=i)
           }
          )
        )
```

Then you can overlay your test points on those polygons:

```
> over(pts2,polys)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
 6 34 NA 32  8 NA 26 NA NA  9 30 NA 36 NA NA 10 NA 34 39 22 34 21 34 10 NA NA
```

which gives the index number of the triangle. So the first point is over triangle 6, which is:

```
> tl[[6]]
  ptNum        x        y
1     2 0.404418 0.625027
2    25 0.678718 0.612262
3     9 0.487887 0.742302
```

made up of points 2, 25, and 9. You can verify this by plotting those three points, then the rest of them, then the first test point:

```
> plot(pts1[c(2,25,9),],pch=19)
> plot(pts1,add=TRUE,pch=3)
> plot(pts2[1,],add=TRUE,pch=19,cex=2,col="blue")
```

and you should see a blue dot in a triangle of black dots - with no plus signs in the triangle!

Comment: A quick note for posterity: In my own data, I first had to assign the right projection to the created polygon shapefile, before I could overlay w/ the point data. With that tweak, it works perfectly!